# How to read "during the 1870's"?

Tags: reading-aloud, dates

> Fyodor Dostoevsky’s novel Demons is a piece that observes Russian ideals during the 1870's.

Maybe a trivial question but I am not sure how to express in a spoken word the date in the form as is above. Is it [*the eighteen seventies*] or is it necessary to say [*the seventies of the nineteenth century*]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct reading for "the 1870's" is "the *eighteen* seventies" even though it describes a time in the *nineteenth* century. I have never heard that time period referred to as "the seventies of the nineteenth century".

Comment: Yes. Above edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The former, actually
You pronounce it as the eighteen seventies, not the seventies of the nineteenth century

So other examples would be:
- 1630's - sixteen thirties
- 1820's - eighteen twenties
- 1960's - nineteen sixties